# Creating number pools

Tags: c++

I created a simple container class, that holds a number from a pool of unique numbers. Then returns the number back to the pool before the container is destroyed.

```
//Pooled.hpp
#pragma once

#include <queue>

class Pooled {
public:
    Pooled();
    ~Pooled();
    //Edit: disable copy and copy assignment here
    const int number;
private:
    int getNumber();
    static std::queue<int> pool;
    static int currentSize;
};
```

and

```
//Pooled.cpp
#include "Pooled.hpp"

std::queue<int> Pooled::pool;
int Pooled::currentSize = 1;

Pooled::Pooled() : number(getNumber()) {}

Pooled::~Pooled() {
    pool.push(number);
}

int Pooled::getNumber() {
    if (pool.empty()) {
        pool.push(currentSize);
        currentSize++;
    }
    int newNumber = pool.front();
    pool.pop();
    return newNumber;
}
```

But let's say I wanted to create multiple pools of numbers. I could define an arbitrary number of `std::queue<int>`s somewhere, then have every `Pooled` object hold a reference to a specific one. But that doubles the size of every `Pooled` object.

Or I could create a class for every pool I need, like `Pooled1`, `Pooled2` which sounds quite dumb, but keeps each object small. Is there any way to accomplish both goals?

Comment: You could maintain a shared `static vector< queue<int> >`.

Comment: use std::vector<std::bitset<N>>
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/

Comment: Templates are a way to create classes for every pool you need without duplicating code.

Comment: Implicit copying is not okay; when the destructors on the copy and the original are done running, you will have two copies of a single number in your pool.

Comment: Right, it does not make sense to allow copying for unique numbers.

Comment: Maybe, use `static std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::queue<int>>>`?